# Is $49931$ the least positive integer $k$, such that $312^{4009}+k$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Denote $$z(k)\ :=\ 312^{4009}+k$$

After a long search, I found the (probable) prime $z(49931)$.

> Questions :
>
> $1)$ Is $k=49931$ the least positive integer, such that $z(k)$ is prime ?
>
> $2)$ Is $z(49931)$ really prime ?

I sieved out the small factors, but there are still many candidates left.
PARI/GP takes about $30$ seconds to check, if $z(k)$ is pseudoprime, so the
search would take very long. Perhaps, someone has a faster program.

Comment: It's the least positive integer such that $z(k)$ is probably prime. Very probably. But I have no proof.

Comment: It's a BPSW, ES BPSW, Frobenius-Underwood, and Frobenius-Khashin PRP, so it's highly likely to be prime.  At 10k digits it is small enough to run through Primo if you have a day or so.  My `next_prime` took 160 minutes to verify it is the next prime, which is surprisingly long, though better than Pari/GP.  Looks like my implementation picks 110,313,657 as the sieve depth with 1560 candidates for BPSW.

Comment: Pari/GP (2.8.0) finished on the same computer after 10h 22m, raising the stack to 64MB as well.  About 3.9x slower, which is within the 3-4x slower I'd expect.  A program calling PFGW for PRP checks (not its nextprime function) or using gwnum to implement a PRP test would likely take less than an hour, at a guess of 3x faster than GMP at this size.