# Least number $k>11$, such that $k+n$ is prime for $n=0,2,6,8,12,18,20,26,30,32$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

The least integer $k>11$, for which $k+n$ is prime for $n=0,2,6,8,12,18,20,26,30,32$, is, according to my search, $k=33,081,664,151$.

The numbers form a prime constellation with length $10$ and width $32$.

> $1)$ Is my number the smallest one ?
>
> $2)$ How can the smallest number be found without brute force ?

Looking at the residue classes $2$,$3$,$5$ and $7$, I found out that $k$
must be of the form $210k+11$, but I did not get further restrictions
for $k$. Of course, I could continue with the residue classes modulo $11,13,... $. Is this the best and only way to restrict $k$, or are there more powerful
methods ?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A027569

Comment: @mathlove this approves, that my number is indeed the minimal one, thanks. But perhaps, someone can give some hints how to accelerate finding such prime constellations.

Comment: After you found some special forms like $210k+11$ you can sieve a list of k's by some prime factors. This should speed up the process considerably.

Comment: polysieve2 (http://mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=400966&postcount=143, also see the rest of the thread for more info) is going to be far faster than what you'd write in Pari/GP, for instance.  I did some experiments with fast sieves and looking at the bit patterns, like it done for twin primes, but while a nice speedup over looking at all primes, again nowhere close to polysieve2.  primesieve has a k-tuplet option, using the `-p5` option then piping through something like Perl/ntheory to check the `k+n` sequence takes 19 seconds on my machine to verify this is the smallest.

Comment: Perl seems to be a miracle-program .

Comment: But the way I programmed it was fast enough in PARI/GP to find this example quickly. I do not know the time it took, however.

Comment: @DanaJ You can calculate this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425245/is-49931-the-least-positive-integer-k-such-that-3124009k-is-prime

Comment: I am not sue, if PARI/GP is too slow, or if the algorithms implemented are too inefficient ...

Comment: The example was finding the first 100 or so of these (out to 4x10^13), which is where polysieve2 (written in C by Robert Gerbicz) really made a difference.  For the `primesieve ... | perl ...` example it's certainly possible to do the last part in Python or Pari/GP, but perl is well set up as a scripting language, so add some good prime-related features (the ntheory module) and it's very convenient to use (IMO).

Comment: @DanaJ I am currently searching the least $k>10^{19}$ producing the above prime constellation. With PARI/GP I searched from $10^{19}+1$ to $10^{19}+451,794,848,611$ and no example was found. Surely, Perl gets a quick result! Perhaps, you let run it for me ...

Comment: @DanaJ the last PARI/GP-version, I have downloaded includes a directory named perl. Is this the program you use, or is it something different belonging to the PARI/GP-package ? I think, it is not the powerful perl ...

Comment: Least k > 10^19 looks like 10^19+5800403630281,  I used primesieve to find pentuples and then piped to a test for testing all conditions.  At this size primesieve is a lot more efficient than my module finding twin primes.  Looks like I should fiddle with the native-int code for twin primes like I did my GMP code, or maybe think about a n-tuple function.

Comment: @Peter, I use Perl the programming language, probably already on your system, with the ntheory module I wrote which has lots of number theory functions.  If you're on Windows, (1) I'm sorry, and (2) Strawberry Perl has everything needed.  Re Pari/gp "too slow", typically it's just not as fast as GMP and some of my functions.  But often by a small linear amount, and one could argue its strengths make up for it.  There are also functions like partitions and tauramanujan which are much better than what I've written, plus lots of functionality I will never have.

Comment: @DanaJ I also found this example by using the chinese remainder theorem, but I did not finish the calculation for the residue class $8$ modulo $11$, but got upto about $2\times 10^{12}$. The residueclasses modulo $2,3,5,7$ are fixed to be $1,2,1,4$, modulo $11$ , there is a choice between $6$ and $8$, modulo $13$ the classes $2,3,4,10,12$ are possible and modulo $17$ the classes $1,3,6,7,10,12,13$ are possible. With this information, one can run the search $70$ times in steps of the size $17\#$, which can be made in reasonable time in PARI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions made me go do some work on this.  It's not released yet, but on github.

```
time perl -Mbigint -Mntheory=:all -E 'say join " ", Math::Prime::Util::GMP::sieve_prime_cluster(1,1e11, 2,6,8,12,18,20,26,30,32);'
11 33081664151 83122625471

real    0m0.161s
user    0m0.148s
sys     0m0.011s

time perl -Mbigint -Mntheory=:all -E 'say join " ", Math::Prime::Util::GMP::sieve_prime_cluster(1e19,1e19+1e13, 2,6,8,12,18,20,26,30,32);'
10000005800403630281

real    0m8.096s
user    0m8.081s
sys     0m0.012s
```

In some examples I've looked at, `polysieve2` is slightly faster, assuming you tune the sieve sizes.  Bad sieve size choices can make it much slower.  It quite likely is much faster on some other cluster combinations.  Your mileage may vary.  The times from JKA's posts suggest his old code is very fast.  There are some OEIS sequences for long clusters that imply someone either had a lot of time or has a really fast program.

1. Use a primorial, e.g. 23# to generate a list of acceptable residues.  I try to choose an appropriate primorial size, stopping at 23# (to keep all residues under 31 bits) or earlier if we have more than ~50k residues or the given range is small.  But you could just pick something.  Matt Anderson uses 13# (30030) for his examples, JKA uses 31#.  Larger primorials are more efficient but the overhead starts growing.
2. Walk through the range in chunks of the primorial size.  We'd like to efficiently sieve further, which can be done using only the base+residue locations.  For primes larger than the primorial prime and the chosen depth (e.g. 1000), we can check divisibility of the offset residues.  If dealing with bigints this is especially nice as only a single bigint modulo is needed per prime, with the rest all being 32-bit calculations.  With a large range you could optimize a bit more and do some of these modulos once before you start walking the range then simple boolean computations can be done for a few of the first primes.  I'm doing that and it really helps.  `polysieve2` is quite fast at this step.
3. Do primality tests on the residues that are left.  Step 1 guaranteed that none of the locations checked have factors <= your primorial prime.  Step 2 made sure nothing has factors under your sieve depth.  `polysieve2` doesn't do this step, meaning you use something else for the final tests.

Step 2 is where most of my time is spent, but of course it's more efficient to at least spend some time there.  Step 1 is pretty straightforward, and if you have a favorite cluster you can do it once by hand if you desired.  This simple thing greatly reduces the number of tests needed.  For this cluster, step 1 gets us down to 8190 residues per 223092870 values.  Step 2 reduces this to under 5 residues left on average with a depth of 1000.  Step 3 does the final check.  For the second example (10^19 to 10^19+10^13) it ended up doing 289341 total BPSW tests.  Typically this is a small part of the time (but may be quite large if the numbers are huge).

The details vary, but I think most of the programs I've seen go through those steps.  1. Use a primorial to find acceptable residues.  2. As we walk the range in primorial-sized steps, sieve further to reduce even more.  3. Primality tests.

Answer (score 1):

You say you got nothing beyond k = 210n + 11, but we also know that k modulo 11 is 6 or 8, which makes k = 2310n + 1271 or 2310n + 1691, and there are only 5 values modulo 13, so there are 10 values modulo 30,030. Plus 7 values modulo 17, so there are 70 values modulo 510,510, or one in 7293.